# Gettings grouped sums from related tables into linq query columns

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, left-join

I would like to query a table (Accounts) and also as part of the query get totals (Total) from another table (AccountPositions). How can I rewrite this sql query as a linq query? Is it as easy as adding a group by statement... but the group by usage is confusing me.

```
select 
(select sum(ap.Quantity * ap.LastPrice) from AccountPositions ap 
  where ap.AccountId = a.Accountid and ap.IsOpen = 0) as Total,
a.AccountId, a.Username, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.AccountNumber
from Accounts a
where a.IsTrading = 1
```

Something like???

```
var query = (from a in _context.Accounts
            join ap in _context.AccountPositions on ap.AccountId = a.AccountId
            where a.IsTrading == true && and ap.IsOpen == true
            select new {
                Total = ap.Sum(r => r.Quantity * r.LastPrice),
                AccountId = a.AccountId,
                Username = a.Username,
                FirstName = a.FirstName,
                LastName = a.LastName,
                AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
                });
```

Desired Result:

```
Total   AccountId   Username    FirstName   LastName    AccountNumber
2500    496         brice       Brian       Rice        U399445
160     508         jdoe        John        Doe         U555322
```

Tables:

```
Accounts
AccountId   Username    FirstName   LastName    AccountNumber   IsTrading
496         brice       Brian       Rice        U399445         1
498         bmarley     Bob         Marley      U443992         0
508         jdoe        John        Doe         U555332         1

AccountPositions
AccountPositionId   AccountId   Quantity    LastPrice   IsOpen
23                  496         10          200         1
24                  496         15          48          0
25                  508         8           20          1
26                  498         18          35          1
27                  496         5           100         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I rewrite this sql query as a linq query? Is it as easy as adding a group by statement...

It's even easier than that, because the SQL query in question uses single aggregate returning correlated subquery in the select clause, so the translation to LINQ is literally one to one - just use the corresponding C# operators and remember that in LINQ `select` goes last. And aggregate methods like `Sum` are outside the LINQ *query syntax*:

```c#
var query =
    from a in _context.Accounts
    where a.IsTrading
    select new
    {
        Total = (from ap in _context.AccountPositions
                 where ap.AccountId == a.AccountId && ap.IsOpen
                 select ap.Quantity * ap.LastPrice).Sum(),
        a.AccountId,
        a.Username,
        a.FirstName,
        a.LastName,
        a.AccountNumber
    };
```

But LINQ allows you to mix *query syntax* with *method syntax*, so the `Sum` part can be written more naturally using the later like this:

```c#
Total = _context.AccountPositions
    .Where(ap => ap.AccountId == a.AccountId && ap.IsOpen)
    .Sum(ap => ap.Quantity * ap.LastPrice),
```

Finally, if you are using Entity Framework, the relationship between the `Account` and `AccountPosition` will be expressed by something like

```c#
public ICollection<AccountPosition> AccountPositions { get; set; }
```

*navigation property* inside `Account` class. Which allows to forget about the join (correlation) conditions like `ap.AccountId == a.AccountId` - they will be applied automatically, and concentrate just on your query logic (see [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)), e.g.

```c#
Total = a.AccountPositions.Where(ap => ap.IsOpen).Sum(ap => ap.Quantity * ap.LastPrice),
```

---

Inside LINQ query, the EF collection navigation property represents the so called [grouped join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins) - an unique LINQ feature (at least doesn't have direct equivalent in SQL). In LINQ *query syntax* it's expressed as `join` + `into` clauses. Let say you need more than one aggregate. Grouped join will help you to achieve that w/o repeating the correlation part.

So with your model, the query using grouped join will start like this:

```c#
from a in _context.Accounts
join ap in _context.AccountPositions on a.AccountId equals ap.AccountId into accountPositions
```

From here you have 2 variables - `a` representing an `Account` and `accountPositions` representing the set of the `AccountPosition` related to that `Account`.

But you are interested only in open positions. In order to avoid repeating that condition, you can use another LINQ *query syntax* construct - the [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) clause. So the query continues with both filters:

```c#
where a.IsTrading
let openPositions = accountPositions.Where(ap => ap.IsOpen)
```

Now you have all the information to produce the final result, for instance:

```c#
select new
{
    // Aggregates
    TotalPrice = openPositions.Sum(ap => ap.Quantity * ap.LastPrice),
    TotalQuantity = openPositions.Sum(ap => ap.Quantity),
    OpenPositions = openPositions.Count(),
    // ...
    // Account info
    a.AccountId,
    a.Username,
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName,
    a.AccountNumber
};
```